# Error while running iphone app in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4

I am converting an iPhone App in to the iPad App,

for that I have changed the  buttons size by "Austosizing" feature in Inspecture  and it resized the buttons and it looks fine in the iPad simulator

All the functionalities were working perfectly in the in the  iPhone simulator

The problem is that when I click buttons in the iPad simulator then only certain buttons are working, the others button look as if they are disabled but as such they are not

The screen resizes to the iPad resolution but screen seems to work only till iphone view dimensions

What could be wrong?

what should be done?

Please Help and Suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want to run your iPhone application in iPad then you must have to create iPad nib's and saved them with "*nibname-iPad*" and also you have to change the .plist file in Other Resource folder with adding option *NSMainNibFile~ipad* as *key* and *MainWindow-iPad* as its *value*

And also remember that wherever you use iPhone nib you must have to change it with iPad nib name.

Answer (score 0):

You have another choice of doing this :

1. Goto your application ***.xcodeproject file** (*first file in left panel*).
2. right click and choose **get info**
3. Under *Deployment* there is **Targeted Device Family** Here select **iPhone/iPad**

**This will make your application work like Universal Application.**

Cheers